# How does one estimate the number of trees and the depth when using random forests?

Tags: r, random-forest

I am using random forests for a class.

I am predicting weight training.

In scikit learn I always used a rule of thumb of a depth of 5, the depth x features rounded.

I had 53 features, rounded to 50 x 5 and got 250 for number of trees.

I picked 250 trees and 5 node depth and got great results.

I got 98% accuracy for my test set (100% for training).

The data set is for coursera machine learning. The data set is at d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/predmachlearn/pml-training.csv I removed seven features that were unrelated. The predictor is classe.

Well, it works again, but I have no formal basis. I would appreciate any guidance,

Comment: The data set is for coursera machine learninng

Comment: I picked 250 trees and 5 node depth and got great results but an not sure why. The data set is at https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/predmachlearn/pml-training.csv I removed seven features that were unrelated. The predictor is classe.

Comment: You should include this information in your question by editing it.